# Getting error findViewById when initiate recyclerview in a fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

I have tested this code in another project where I didn't use fragment and wrote it in MainActivity.kt, it works. But a problem comes when I make another project using fragment so I write it in a new class (HerbalFragment.kt). It's getting error in "findViewById" for initiate Recyclerview and also getting error in "this". Here is my code (HerbalFragment.kt)

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

/**
 * A simple [Fragment] subclass.
 */
class HerbalFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var rvHerbal: RecyclerView
    private var list: ArrayList<Herbal> = arrayListOf()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_herbal, container, false)

        rvHerbal = findViewById(R.id.rv_herbal)
        rvHerbal.setHasFixedSize(true)
        list.addAll(HerbalData.listData)
        showRecyclerList()
    }

    private fun showRecyclerList() {
        rvHerbal.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        val listHerbalAdapter = ListHerbalAdapter(list)
        rvHerbal.adapter = listHerbalAdapter
    }
}[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Help me please, thanks before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i have noticed your code is unreachable,

```
 override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_herbal, container, false)

    // unreachable code you are already return the view so below code will never execute
    rvHerbal = findViewById(R.id.rv_herbal)
    rvHerbal.setHasFixedSize(true)
    list.addAll(HerbalData.listData)
    showRecyclerList()
}
```

To fix this issue you need to change your code as i have suggested.

```
 override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

     return  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_herbal, container, false)


}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
   // do what ever you want here like find view ids and etc...
      rvHerbal = findViewById(R.id.rv_herbal)
rvHerbal.setHasFixedSize(true)
list.addAll(HerbalData.listData)
showRecyclerList()

    }
}

 private fun showRecyclerList() {
    rvHerbal.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity!!)
    val listHerbalAdapter = ListHerbalAdapter(list)
    rvHerbal.adapter = listHerbalAdapter
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your solution is similar with other answer and both of u are right, but why after running my app is force closed? Do u know why?

Comment: Might be possible you are doing heavy operation in main thread. that's why. You need to do heavy operation in background thread. To debug it i need your adapter and HerbalData class code.

Comment: shahid17june Thanks for ur help. I think it should be in a new question. Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: @MeyLin Please vote the answer if it helps you, So that others can get also benifients from this answer.

Comment: Hi I've just voted answer. I'm so sorry, both of you seems to give me a same answer that's why I don't know whom to be voted. I really appreciated you and other answer, thanks before.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to find view if you use the kotlin data binding by this easy method

add import to this (fragment_herbal is your xml layout view file name)

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_herbal.*
```

then

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_herbal, container, false)
}
```

then use your view item without findviewbyid

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    rvHerbal.setHasFixedSize(true)
    list.addAll(HerbalData.listData)
    showRecyclerList()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the import statement when I added, I got notification it's unused so I delete it. Your solution is right, but why after running my app is force closed? Do u know why?

Comment: Copy the the log please. and notice that I use the items in "onViewCreated" function not in "onCreateView".

Comment: Thanks for ur help. I will try to fix it as your suggest and If I get an error again, I think it should be in a new question. Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Hi I've just voted answer. I'm so sorry, both of you seems to give me a same answer that's why I don't know whom to be voted. I really appreciated you and other answer, thanks before.